# How to get RAM map?

Tags: memory, dd, proc, ram, dump

I had read a [topic](http://gabrieletolomei.wordpress.com/miscellanea/operating-systems/in-memory-layout/) by Gabriele Tolomei about map of Linux memory. I want to make a memory map for my Linux Ubuntu 16.04, using basic utilities, like dd and xxd, and I want to compare my result with result from topic.

I have dump of Linux Swap Partition after system goes to hibernation. Also I have all information from /proc and /sys directories.
How can I do something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJ0dy.png)?

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1401595/2954288, alas you would need to get the map for each process individually and assemble the result.

Comment: @Harald, I agree with You, but not at all. I want to get full map of memory, not only map of process's memory. In /proc/ID/maps, we can't see Kernel memory.

Comment: Have a look at `/proc/iomem` and `/proc/vmallocinfo`, but I'm not sure if these are the complete mappings. BTW, the "this" link you gave points to the virtual memory view of a single process, not all mappings from virtual to physical memory (what you seem to be asking about). And swap space may use a totally different addressing scheme.

Comment: @dirkt Yes, this way is much better. Several days ago I done that and I can tell that /proc/iomem use the same address space as swap, except adress space for block devices. For example, /proc/iomem has 9.25Gb in space, but RAM is only 8Gb

Comment: Huh? /proc/iomem mainly lists the memory mapped I/O devices (with some physical RAM thrown in between), so of course the total size of all areas will be more than physical RAM. You can have *any* amount of swap space (none, less than your RAM, more than your RAM). The whole *point* of having swap is to allow your processes to use more memory than available physical RAM (*much* more memory on early systems). So the OS is free to use whatever address scheme for swap space it likes.

Comment: Maybe I have mistakes, but I think, when I use size of swap (= hibernation) partition with the same size as RAM, adress space looks the same in /proc/iomem and in swap partirion (after system goes to hibernation).